# How to align children of different height in a tikz-tree?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-trees

When producing a tree diagram I came across following problem:

In a tree growing down, the children do not align if their heights are different.

Example 1: The children of 'foo' are called 'A' and 'a'. The little 'a' is aligned top with the big 'A'.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=down}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\Tree [.foo [.A ]
            [.a ]]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Now the easy way out is changing the anchor from `anchor=north` to `anchor=south`, which works fine **IF** the children consist of one line only. (The vertical length of the branch is changed then, which is fine.)

But how to get following children aligned line-wise?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{grow'=down}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\Tree [.foo [.A\\A ]
            [.a\\a ]]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\strut` to let both letters have the same height and depth, or measure the height of `A` and make `a` of the same height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{grow'=down}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\tikzset
  {edge from parent/.style=
    {draw,
     edge from parent path=
      {(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt)-| (\tikzchildnode)
      }
    }
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Tree [.foo [.\strut A\\A ]
              [.\strut a\\a ]]
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\newlength\heightA
\settoheight\heightA{A}
\newcommand\strutA{\rule{0pt}{\heightA}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Tree [.foo [.A\\A ]
              [.\strutA a\\a ]]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and pointing out two ways of using \struct.